# Calling a private VBA subroutine with Parameter

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA Add-In which is supposed to add functionality to several worksheets. I have a class to listen for worksheet events and trigger macros. This works but I can't seem to call private macros with parameters from it.

My event listener is in a class module and is this:

```
Option Explicit
Private WithEvents App As Application

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set App = Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Source As Range)
    On Error GoTo Finish
    App.EnableEvents = False
    Call Application.Run("Worksheet_Change", "Source")
 Finish:
    App.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It is initialized on opening the workbook in a module like so:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
    Set clsAppEvents = New clsApplicationEvents
End Sub
```

And the macro I'm trying to call is in a separate module again and takes the form:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'Do some work on range
End Sub
```

I've tried the following ways of calling the macro and none have worked so far:

```
Call Application.Run("Worksheet_Change", "Source")
Application.Run "Worksheet_Change", "Source"
Application.Run "Worksheet_Change" "Source"
```

Comment: It would help to include the error you get when you try this.  In any case, the most obvious problem seems to be that you're passing `Source` as a string instead of a Range object.  Try removing the quotes around Source in your call to Run.

Comment: I didn't have an error message the macro simply didn't run however removing the quotes like so: Application.Run "Worksheet_Change", Source - Did the trick. If you want to make an answer I'll mark it as solved. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arguments to Run don't all have to be strings, so

```
Application.Run "Worksheet_Change", "Source"
```

Should be

```
Application.Run "Worksheet_Change", Source
```